# android layout drag and move to other layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

is it possible to move whole layout on the screen on top of all other view and layout without using framelayout? if yes then how?

currently i am using relativelayout as parent and many other layout as child and i want to move view on whole screen with finger touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes a drag and drop api is available but the api is only available for android honeycomb